# Time disparity between posting and commenting

Tags: bug, status-declined

I have posted a question on SO and had one comment.

The time of comment is however earlier than that of my question post.[image]

Comment: Should have been some caching problem probably, because currently the time I see if 17mins ago for the question and 16 mins ago for the comment.

Comment: Yeah it is perfect now...

Comment: I feel bad for people who have to stare at that annoying careers ad…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second comment in your screenshot (your reply to Cody) has a "just now" timestamp, which probably means you took this screenshot immediately after posting said comment.

Posting a new comment causes the full comments section to be re-rendered and inserted into the page, but it doesn't touch the question itself.

Thus the question's timestamp was created when the full page was originally rendered, but the comment's timestamp was rendered later.

So much for the explanation. In spite of you being absolutely correct, I'm declining this for now, since it's not really a major problem, and it should've been auto-fixed within less than 60 seconds.

We may at some point decide to ensure that all timestamps on a page are *always* in sync after a partial update, but that should handle more than just this particular case.